# PixelSearch returns X=0, Y=0 coordinates

Tags: c#, autoit-c#-wrapper

I'm using AutoItX library to search for a pixel in a certain area. Unfortunately it always returns X=0, Y=0 on whatever coordinates or color for the `PixelSearch` method. I can't find any documentation either.

Code:

```
var rgb = desiredPixelColor.ToArgb();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()
{
    X = 200,
    Y = 200,
    Width = 400,
    Height = 400
};

try
{
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById(ID);
    if (p != null)
    {
        IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(h);

        var search = AutoItX.PixelSearch(rect, rgb);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (!search.IsEmpty)
        {
            DoubleClickAtPos(search.X, search.Y);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
 catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("No pixel found");

}
```

No matter what coordinates or color, `PixelSearch` always returns 0 values. Not even null. Also tried smaller values but the result is always the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PixelSearch in certain area of monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553291/pixelsearch-in-certain-area-of-monitor)